# How to convert array into a tree structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, tree

This is my array. I am just trying to frame a hierarchy tree with grandparent->parent->child name relationship. Please help me fix this.
Sample input will be like below

```
data = 
[
{name:'111',parent:'11',grandparent:'1'},
{name:'112',parent:'11',grandparent:'1'},
{name:'121',parent:'12',grandparent:'1'},
{name:'211',parent:'21',grandparent:'2'}
]
```

Expected Output is something like this. Please ignore if any syntax errors

```
[
    {
    name:'1',
    children:[
              {
                name:'11',
                children:[
                    {
                        name:'111',
                        children:[]
                    },
                    {
                        name:'112',
                        children:[]
                    }
                ]
              },
              {
                  name:'12',
                  children:[
                    {
                        name:'121',
                        children:[]
                    }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  name:'21',
                  children:[
                    {
                        name:'211',
                        children:[]
                    }

                  ]
              }
            
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: was just trying something but couldnt move it after level 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` and `forEach` methods to create nested structure and also one array where you can specify the order of keys that you want to iterate by.

```js
const data = [{"name":"111","parent":"11","grandparent":"1"},{"name":"112","parent":"11","grandparent":"1"},{"name":"121","parent":"12","grandparent":"1"},{"name":"211","parent":"21","grandparent":"2"}]

const order = ['grandparent', 'parent', 'name'];
const result = [];
const levels = {result}

data.forEach(o => {
  order.reduce((r, e) => {
    const name = o[e];
    if (!r[name]) {
      const value = {name, children: []}
      r[name] = {result: value.children}
      r.result.push(value)
    }

    return r[name]
  }, levels)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: interesting approach. where do you have it from?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Nenad Vracar answer if you want to use as dynamic array values use `Object.keys()` and `reverse`

```js
const data = [{"name":"111","parent":"11","grandparent":"1"},{"name":"112","parent":"11","grandparent":"1"},{"name":"121","parent":"12","grandparent":"1"},{"name":"211","parent":"21","grandparent":"2", "grandgrandparente": "3"}]


const result = [];
const levels = {result}

data.forEach(o => {
  const order = Object.keys(o).reverse();
  order.reduce((r, e) => {
    const name = o[e];
    if (!r[name]) {
      const value = {name, children: []}
      r[name] = {result: value.children}
      r.result.push(value)
    }

    return r[name]
  }, levels)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking to modify it according to dynamic one later. but thanks for your solution which does that . @PabloWeb18 :)